# How do I generify the error of a Rust Result<T, E> to Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>?

Tags: rust, reqwest, rust-result

I am trying to generify a `Result` that is returned by the [`reqwest::blocking::get`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/blocking/fn.get.html) function. It returns a `Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>` but the function it is called in returns a `Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, Box<dyn std::error::Error>`.

- Why does my first attempt fail to compile?
- What is the most idiomatic way to make this conversion?

This is the first attempt:

```rust
fn get_example_fails() -> Result<Response, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let result = blocking::get("http://example.com");
        result.map_err(|error| Box::new(error))
    }
```

It has the following error which I do not know how to fix but feel it might be more idiomatic with some minor tweaking - but am not sure what to tweak:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/bittrex.rs:143:9
    |
141 |     fn get_example_fails() -> Result<Response, Box<dyn Error>> {
    |                               -------------------------------- expected `Result<reqwes
t::blocking::Response, Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)>>` because of return type
142 |         let result = blocking::get("http://example.com");
143 |         result.map_err(|error| Box::new(error))
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn StdError`, 
found struct `reqwest::Error`
    |
    = note: expected enum `Result<_, Box<(dyn StdError + 'static)>>`
               found enum `Result<_, Box<reqwest::Error>>`
```

This attempt compiles but seems verbose:

```rust
fn get_example_works() -> Result<Response, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let result = blocking::get("http://example.com");
        match result {
            Ok(resp) => Ok(resp),
            Err(error) => Err(Box::new(error)),
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the compiler is overzealous here. Notice that `Box::new(error)` simply puts `error` in a `Box`, so you get a strongly typed `Box<reqwest:Error>`, just as the compiler reports. But what you want is a trait object for `dyn Error`, which `Box<reqwest:Error>` could be, but the compiler does not make that type-weakening assumption. The fix is manually make that clear:

```
fn get_example_fails() -> Result<Response, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let result = blocking::get("http://example.com");
        result.map_err(|error| Box::new(error) as Box<dyn Error>)
}
```

Notice the extra `as Box<dyn Error>`, which makes clear to the compiler that the value should be downcasted and where the fact that it is a concrete `reqwest::Error` that is in the `Box` should be erased.

The reason why the second example compiles fine is type inference. In the first example, the type returned from the function will be the type returned from `.map_err()`, which is a `Result<Response, Box<reqwest::Error>>` - that's it. The type does not match, so you get an error. In the second example, the `match` constructs a whole new `Result` and Rust has to infer the `T` and `E` for that; so type inference kicks in. In this second case, the inference due to the function's return value is successful with respect to `Box<dyn Error>`. But with `map_err()`, the type inference can't "look into" the `map_err()`-body and weaken *it's* return type; its already too late, the type is fixed. That's why you have to do it manually as advised above.

Comment: "But what you want is a trait object for `dyn Error`, which `Box<reqwest:Error>` could be" I would disagree. You can _create_ a `Box<dyn Error>` from a `Box<reqwest:Error>`, but a `Box<reqwest:Error>` can't _be_ (or "be used as", etc.) a `Box<dyn Error>` (e.g. because `Box<reqwest:Error>` internally contains just one pointer but `Box<dyn Error>` contains two).